# Undefined reference ld linker. (C++)

Tags: c++, linker

I wrote a code split into several .h, .cpp files
two functions take string type arguments (the code fragment below)
I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclLgueo.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `doloop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to 
`detect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does it mean?
Code:

```
//File: main.cpp (fragment)
string loop;
doloop(loop);
```

Header:

```
#ifndef func_h
#define func_h
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void detect(string cmd);
... void
void doloop(string con);
... void
#endif
```

func.cpp:

```
void doloop(string con)
{
short y; // Fragment
}
//detect function is similar
```

##Compiler command: "g++ main.cpp"

Comment: What is your compilation command?

Comment: I just reminded myself of that
"g ++ main.cpp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile all the translation units:

```
g++ func.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBT2Up3.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `board'; /tmp/ccd85wOB.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBT2Up3.o:(.bss+0x1d4c0): multiple definition of `pointer'; /tmp/ccd85wOB.o:(.bss+0x1d4c0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Maniues Add guards (e.g. `#pragma once`) to your header files as well.

Comment: I added and the error still occurs

Comment: I replicated the source and headers from your question and it compiles normally (given you are including the header file in correct source files).

Comment: I have got 2 headers:
vars.h
func.h
in vars.h I have got int *pointer and int board[1000]

in main.cpp / func.cpp:
#include "vars.h"
#include "func.h>

Comment: You are getting an error because of a header which I can’t see and hence can’t fix. Also, the issue is no longer related to compilation but definition of your header files, so post them all. Ask your issue in a separate question and mark this answer as accepted to close the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post next question...

Comment: You mentioned the content in `vars.h`, what does `func.h` contain?

Comment: vars.h - variables. func.h - functions (for example: int function(); )